# Cookies não são salvos - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies

Estou tentado salvar o nome de um usuário através de cookies, mas por algum motivo esses cookies não são salvos. Estou utilizando o [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) do W3schools, mas mesmo criando meu código igual ao deles, ele não funciona.

Aqui é o meu label:

```
    <div id="jogador">
        <h3>Bem vindo ao jogo da memória da Familia Addams!</h3>
        <h4>Digite seu nome para começar</h4>
        <input id="nome-usuario" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
        <input type="button" value="Começar" onclick="iniciar()">
    </div>
```

Antes do fechamento do body eu importo:

```
<script src="JS/jogoMemoria.js"></script>
```

As funções de manipulação dos cookies são:

```
// Função para setar o nome do usuario nos cookies
function setCookies(cookieName, cookieValue) {
    var expires = "expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
}

// Função para obter os cookies
function getCookies(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

// Função do botão começar
function iniciar() {
    var nomeUsuario = document.getElementById("nome-usuario");
    setCookies("username",nomeUsuario.value);
}
```

Ao tentar fazer `console.log(getCookies("username"))` o retorno é undefined. O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Matheus, qual a URL você está usando no navegador? É tipo `http://localhost`? Ou é tipo `C:\nome da pasta\nome do arquivo.html`?

Comment: É do tipo C:\nome da pasta\nome do arquivo.html.

Comment: O navegador não salva cookie para arquivos html locais. Você deve subir um servidor tipo apache ou nginx, tem a suite xampp ou wampp que é bem simples, configura um servidor destes que vai dar certo. Quando sair de `file://c:\xyz.html` para `http://xyz` ele vai manipular os cookies certinho.

Comment: Obrigado! Isso resolveu o problema.